# Searching date columns in database having nvarchar data types

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to search for all the date columns that could reside in a database. The problem is there are many date columns that are of the data type `nvarchar` and the column names also don't hint that it is a date column.

The date stored in these columns could also be of any date format. I tried using `isdate()` but `isdate` does not recognize `dd-mm-yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mmm-dd-yyyy` (Jun-06-2014).

Is there a way to identify these columns?

Answer (score 0):

I probably spent too much time on this, but I think I have an answer.  The following code, based on the three data formats you mentioned (and using some of the easy ones available to the `CONVERT()` function), will list out all the fields in the database that can be converted using those formats.

Couple of important notes here:

1) the query currently only checks columns with VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, CHAR, NCHAR, DATE, and DATETIME data types.

2) the query only checks for specific formats - the three you mentioned, anything SQL can handle implicitly, and the various format codes that can be passed to the `CONVERT()` function.  Any other special ones will have to be added manually, by copying the last chunk starting with `BEGIN TRY` and ending with `END CATCH`.  If you know of a format, Google can find you SQL code to use it, just add it in.

```
CREATE TABLE #ListOfColumnsToCheck
  (
    ListID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TableName VARCHAR(100),
    ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
  )

INSERT INTO #ListOfColumnsToCheck (TableName, ColumnName)
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE DATA_TYPE IN -- expand this list as necessary
  (
    'VARCHAR',
    'NVARCHAR',
    'CHAR',
    'NCHAR',
    'DATETIME',
    'DATE'
  )

CREATE TABLE #DateCheck (DateValue DATE)

CREATE TABLE #Results  
  (
    TableName VARCHAR(100),
    ColumnName VARCHAR(100),
    ConvertsToDate BIT
  )


DECLARE @LoopCounter INT 
DECLARE @LoopFinishNumber INT
DECLARE @CurrentTableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CurrentColumnName VARCHAR(100)

SET @LoopCounter = 1
SET @LoopFinishNumber = (SELECT MAX(ListID) FROM #ListOfColumnsToCheck)


WHILE @LoopCounter <= @LoopFinishNumber
  BEGIN

    SELECT @CurrentColumnName = ColumnName, @CurrentTableName = TableName
    FROM #ListOfColumnsToCheck
    WHERE ListID = @LoopCounter

    BEGIN TRY -- add additional date formats to these lists as you come across them
    EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1 ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' 
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

    INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
    VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
    END CATCH

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',101)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',102)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',103)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',104)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',105)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',106)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',107)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',108)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',109)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',110)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',111)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',112)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',113)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1  CONVERT(DATETIME, '+@CurrentColumnName+',114)
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   

    -- start of code block (when copying/pasting, start here)
    BEGIN TRY
      EXEC('
        INSERT INTO #DateCheck (DateValue) 
        SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE('+@CurrentColumnName+', ''-'', '' '')
        FROM ' + @CurrentTableName + '
        WHERE ' + @CurrentColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL')

      INSERT INTO #Results (TableName, ColumnName, ConvertsToDate)
      VALUES (@CurrentTableName, @CurrentColumnName, 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
      PRINT @CurrentTableName + '.' + @CurrentColumnName + ' is not a valid date'
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   
    -- end of code block (when copying/pasting, end here then change the SELECT TOP 1 statement to use the format)

    SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1

  END

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #Results


DROP TABLE #DateCheck
DROP TABLE #ListOfColumnsToCheck
DROP TABLE #Results
```